# Is it possible to use two versions of MS reporting library in one asp.net site/ DNN site

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc, dotnetnuke

Is it possible to use different versions of MS reporting library say 8 and 10 (Report viewer and rdlc compiler) in one asp.net site? I have tried to use this because I wanted to install two DNN modules in one DNN site which use different versions report viewer and compiler and found out that it is impossible. I have put web.config files in each module sub directory but can not use ! ( can be used only in maching config and applicaion root path.) so how can I use two different reporting versions 8 and 10 in one DNN site for different modules?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have assemblies in GAC. This is common way in .net to have different versions of same component.

You may want to search term "side by side".